# Google Analytics search tracking with events

Tags: search, google-analytics

I have enabled "Site search Tracking" in Google Analytics.
Is there a way to send users search terms with events instead of pageviews? I am using it for an instant-search on a webshop so I dont want to send each tracking as a pageview.

Answer (score 0):

*Site search Tracking* functionality in View Settings only works when parameters are in queryString of a `pageview`.

I tried out of curiosity by managing the queryString in a page associated with an `event` hit and I can confirm that **it does not work**, the search terms are acquired in the report only when they are sent with pageview hits.